# How to fix category view calling as age_rate category that dosen't work in template

Tags: python, django

I want to show views results in template django app named as core but it dosen't work properly, where is the problem?

There is two model for two kind of category one as Category and another as AgeRate. Category will categorize books based on genre and AgeRate will categorize them by age rates that for now includes (A, B ,C) rates.
now in template I'll try to show the results of age rate but dosen't work properly.

model.py

```py
class Category(TranslatableModel):
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        name=models.CharField(max_length=200,
                              db_index=True),
        slug=models.SlugField(max_length=200,
                              db_index=True,
                              unique=True),
    )

    class Meta:
        # ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('core:product_list_by_category',
                       args=[self.slug])

class AgeRate(TranslatableModel):
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        age_rate=models.CharField(max_length=3),
        slug=models.SlugField(max_length=4,
                              db_index=True,
                              unique=True, default='')
    )

    class Meta:
        # ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'age_rate'
        verbose_name_plural = 'age_rates'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.age_rate

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('core:product_list_by_age_rate',
                       args=[self.slug])

class Product(TranslatableModel):
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        name=models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True),
        slug=models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True),
        description=models.TextField(blank=True),
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,
                                 related_name='products',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    age_rate = models.ForeignKey(AgeRate, related_name='products_by_age',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 default='')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d',
                              blank=True)

    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    # class Meta:
    #     ordering = ('name',)
    #     index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('core:product_detail',
                       args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

core:url.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.core, name='core'),
    path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list,
         name='product_list_by_category'),
    path('<slug:age_rate_slug>/', views.core,
         name='product_list_by_age_rate')
]
```

main:url.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('account/', include('account.urls')),
    path('', include('core.urls', namespace='core')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py

```py
def core(request, age_rate_slug=None):
    age_rate = None
    age_rates = AgeRate.objects.all()
    products_by_age = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if age_rate_slug:
        language = request.LANGUAGE_CODE
        age_rate = get_object_or_404(AgeRate,
                                     translations__language_code=language,
                                     translations__slug=age_rate_slug)
        products_by_age = products_by_age.filter(age_rate=age_rate)
    if request.method == 'POST':
       if 'send_msg' in request.POST:
            # contact_us(request)
            form = ContactForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Profile updated successfully')
                return redirect(reverse_lazy('core:core'))
            else:
                return HttpResponse('form is invalid')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('send_msg didn\'t work')
    else:

        form = ContactForm()

        return render(request, 'core/core.html',
                      {'form': form,
                       'products_by_age': products_by_age,
                       'age_rate': age_rate,
                       'age_rates': age_rates})

def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    # We use an optional category_slug parameter to
    # optionally filter products by a given category.
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)

    if category_slug:
        language = request.LANGUAGE_CODE
        # Translate category
        category = get_object_or_404(Category,
                                     translations__language_code=language,
                                     translations__slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)

    return render(request,
                  'core/core.html',
                  {'category': category,
                   'categories': categories,
                   'products': products})
```

template

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>ستاره کوچولو</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="{% static "core/css/bootstrap.css" %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "core/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" %}">
<!-- Stylesheet
    ================================================== -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="{% static "core/css/style.css" %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "core/css/nivo-lightbox/nivo-lightbox.css" %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "core/css/nivo-lightbox/default.css" %}">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800,600,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
<!-- Navigation
    ==========================================-->
<nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top"><i class="fa fa-play fa-rotate-270"></i> # </a> </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#page-top" class="page-scroll">خانه</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about" class="page-scroll">درباره ما</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio" class="page-scroll">محصولات</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact" class="page-scroll">ارتبا با ما</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html" class="page-scroll">ورود</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="page-scroll">ثبت نام</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
    <!-- Header -->
<header id="header">
  <div class="intro">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="intro-text">
          <h1>#</h1>
          <p># </p>
          <a href="#about" class="btn btn-custom btn-lg page-scroll">سفارش محصول</a> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<!-- About Section -->
<div id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section-title text-center center">
      <h2>درباره ما</h2>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"> <img src="{% static "core/img/about.jpg" %}" class="img-responsive" alt=""> </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="about-text">
          <p># </p>
          <p> # </p>
          <a href="#portfolio" class="btn btn-default btn-lg page-scroll">محصولات</a> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Portfolio Section -->
<div id="portfolio">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section-title text-center center">
      <h2>محصولات</h2>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="categories">
      <ul class="cat">
        <li>
          <ol class="type">
            <li style="margin-bottom: 25px;"><a href="{% url "core:core" %}" data-filter="*" class="active">ALL</a></li>
              {% for p in product_by_age %}
                <li style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
                    <a href="{{ p.age_rate.get_absolute_url }}" data-filter=".product"> Age rate {{ p.age_rate }}</a>
                </li>
              {% endfor %}
            <li style="direction:rtl;"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="search"></li>
            <li style="margin-left: 30px;"><a href="#"><button class="search-btn">جستجو</button></a></li>
          </ol>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="portfolio-items">
      {% for product in products %}
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 web">
          <div class="portfolio-item">
            <div class="hover-bg"> <a href="{% static "core/img/portfolio/01-large.jpg" %}" title="Project Title" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1">
              <div class="hover-text">
                <h4>{% if category %}{{ category.name }}{% else %}محصولات{% endif %}</h4>
              </div>
                  <img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% else %}{% static "core/img/no_image.png" %}{% endif %}" class="img-responsive" alt="Project Title"></a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Contact Section -->
<div id="contact" class="text-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section-title center">
      <h2>ارتباط با ما</h2>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <form name="sentMessage" action="{% url "core:core" %}" method="post" id="contactForm" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
          {% if messages %}
              <ul class="messages">
                {% for message in messages %}
                    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
          {% endif %}
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div style="direction: rtl" class="form-group">
                  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="ایمیل" required="required">
                  <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
              </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div style="direction: rtl" class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="نام" required="required">
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div style="direction: rtl" class="form-group">
          <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="پیام" required></textarea>
          <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="success"></div>
        <button type="submit" name="send_msg" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">ارسال پیام</button>
      </form>
      <div class="social">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"><span> تلفن </span></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-telegram" aria-hidden="true"><span> تلگرام </span></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"><span> اینستاگرام </span></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"><span> واتس آپ </span></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="fnav">
      <p> # </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "core/js/jquery.1.11.1.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "core/js/bootstrap.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "core/js/SmoothScroll.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "core/js/nivo-lightbox.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "core/js/jquery.isotope.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "core/js/jqBootstrapValidation.js" %}"></script>
{#<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "core/js/contact_me.js" %}"></script>#}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "core/js/main.js" %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

template just shows:
Age rate A - Age rate B - and ...
it doesn't show any product with age rate categories.

**Update:**

I have two important part in the template:
First I want to show all products based on Age Rate that includes A, B and C in home page this is a kind of categorizing, in other hand I have another category model based on genre that I want to use that in Order page.now when I click on (ALL), (AGE RATE A) or (AGE RATE B) in home page I can't see products based on that link. you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5SeK.png).
In admin panel I have [A and B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbxJ5.png) Age Rate that their link names shown properly [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5SeK.png).

when I click on for example (AGE RATE A) link, URL is like this: http://127.0.0.1/a/.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDAUA.png) is one of Products instance in admin page and [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miIv7.png) is category instance.

Second in Home page when I scrolling down there is a form for contact, that  works fine.

First I used product_list function in views for showing age rates and category together in one function but because I want to show age rate in home page, urls should be like:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.core, name='core'),
    path('', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    # ....
]
```

and thats not working because both pointed out in same url so I embedded the code inside core function in views, using that core function for contact form.

that was all what I done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add products_by_age to your template.  Something like

```
{% for p in products_by_age %}
...
```

RESPONSE TO UPDATE

`product_by_age` in template should be `products_by_age`

Also your 2 URL patterns need to be different, something like:

```
path('category/<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list,
    name='product_list_by_category'),
path('age/<slug:age_rate_slug>/', views.core,
    name='product_list_by_age_rate')
```

Then use http://127.0.0.1/age/a/ . Otherwise http://127.0.0.1/a/ will match the *first* path and try to use 'a' as a category_slug.

Comment: changed template code like this but it dosen't work too.

`{% for p in product_by_age %}
        <li style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
            <a href="{{ p.age_rate.get_absolute_url }}" data-filter=".product"> Age rate  {{ p.age_rate }}</a>
        </li>
{% endfor %}`

Comment: What else do you want it to show?  You could include `{{ p.category }}` but I notice that Product doesn't have any Name field.  `{{ p.pk }}` might help you see what it is doing.

Comment: I want, when I clicked on ages links like A, it show me all products based on A age rate. but it doesn't show anything. problem come from `href="{{ p.age_rate.get_absolute_url }}` but I can't figure it out why

Comment: Product has no `__str__` method so it is not clear how it would be displayed.  Can you give an example Product instance?

Comment: Product has a  `__str__` methed. but I didn't put complete code here, now i did it.
please check the codes again

Comment: I see you have added another view now, so it is not clear which one you are talking about.  Please include the URL you are accessing, the full template, the result you see and what you expect.

Comment: After some changes to other parts of codes, I did what you said, and now my code is working, Thank you